# How to implement sweet alert loading and the thick view in our layout?

Tags: android, animation, sweetalert

I know how to user [Sweet Alert library](https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog), but i want to implement the loading and the thick animations in my activity layout and properly control it. how can i do that?

At first,I want to show the loading layout until the background task finishes:

[image]

Then if the task succeed, show the thick animation or fail animation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this in a new library project here:
https://github.com/mori-honest/Sweet-Layout